# Firebase is Not Sending OTP

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to send OTP but this gives me an error like below , i try many thing but all get failed, i also use BARD Ai to handle this but the ai also get failed to do this. In my firebase, I have successfully implemented the authentication where the phone verify get enabled.

I am not using any recaptcha in it but why this error gets shown don't know

> Sending OTP failed TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'verify')
> at _verifyPhoneNumber (phone.ts:178:41)
> at signInWithPhoneNumber (phone.ts:106:32)
> at HTMLFormElement. (home.html:42:17)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>WebChat</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css">
    <script type="module">
        import { initializeApp } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.0/firebase-app.js';
        import { getAuth, signInWithPhoneNumber } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.0/firebase-auth.js';

        // Initialize Firebase
        // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: "YOUR_API_KEY",
            authDomain: "YOUR_AUTH_DOMAIN",
            projectId: "YOUR_PROJECT_ID",
            storageBucket: "YOUR_STORAGE_BUCKET",
            messagingSenderId: "YOUR_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID",
            appId: "YOUR_APP_ID",
            measurementId: "YOUR_MEASUREMENT_ID"
        };

        const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        const auth = getAuth(app);

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            document.getElementById('phone-verification-form').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                // Get the country code and phone number
                const countryCodeElement = document.getElementById('country-code');
                const phoneNumberElement = document.getElementById('phone-number');
                const countryCode = countryCodeElement.value;
                const phoneNumber = phoneNumberElement.value;

                // Concatenate the country code and phone number
                const fullPhoneNumber = `${countryCode}${phoneNumber}`;

                // Use Firebase to send OTP
                signInWithPhoneNumber(auth, fullPhoneNumber)
                    .then((confirmationResult) => {
                        // Redirect to OTP verification page or perform necessary actions
                        window.location.href = '../../../Frontend/Login-Module/OTP-Screen/otp.html';
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        console.error('Sending OTP failed', error);
                    });
            });
        });
    </script>
    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="topuppergreen">
                <div class="logo">
                    <img src="../../../assets/logo.svg" alt="" srcset="">
                    <span>WHATSAPP WEB</span>
                </div>
        </div>

        <div class="maincontent">

            <div class="phoneno">
                <div class="z">
                    <span class="x">Enter Phone Number</span>
                </div>
                <p class="y">Select a country and enter your WhatsApp phone number.</p>

                <div class="form">
                    <form class="mainform" id="phone-verification-form" >
                        <div class="choosecountry">
                            <select name="" id="country-code">
                                <option value="+91">  India</option>
                            </select>
                            <!-- <img src="../../../assets/down-side-arrow.svg" alt="" srcset="" style="width: 10px;height: 10px;"> -->
                        </div>

                        <input type="tel" id="phone-number" placeholder="Enter Your Phone Number">
                        <!-- invisible reCAPTCHA element -->
                        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Ld4b_EoAAAAAK_R1z8AOkH1N5vJKy0-nL1YGspG" style="display: none;"></div>
                        
                        <button >NEXT</button>
                        
                    </form>
                </div>

                <div class="linkqr">
                    <span><a href="#">Link With QR Code</a></span>
                </div>

                <div class="tutorial">
                    <span>Tutorial</span>

                    <p>Need Help To Get Started?</p>

                    <div class="img">
                        <img class="tutorialimg" src="../../../assets/qr-video-hq_c001ebd6ddb0ba5fc7de491dfb556024.png" alt="" srcset="">
                        <div class="playicon">
                            <img class="playiconsvg" src="../../../assets/play.svg" alt="" srcset="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the auth object that you are passing to `signInWithPhoneNumber` and `phoneNumber` itself are not `undefined`